# How to use a static and an instance method with the same name on the same class?

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I am trying to recreate Laravel ORM ([Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)).

In Laravel we can do something like:

```
Model::where("condition1")->where("condition2")->get();
```

So far my attempts to recreate this lead me to write this code:

```
class DB {

    static $condition ;

    public static function chidlClassName() {
        return get_called_class();
    }

    static function where( $cond ) {  

        self::$condition[] = $cond;
        return new DB();
    }

    public function where( $cond ){

        self::$condition[] = $cond ;
        return $this; 
    }


    function get(){

        $cond = implode(' AND ' ,self::$condition);
    }
}

class Modle extends DB {}
```

But it wont work because both `where` functions have the same name...

How does the Laravel do it?

Comment: @yivi thanx for the answer , im reading about magic functions and trying some codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen how Eloquent does it, but way to achieve this would be **not** to declare the method you want to reuse in neither the base class, nor the extended class; and instead use [the magic methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) `__call($method, $arguments)` and `__callStatic($method, $arguments)`.

A simple example would be this:

```php
class Base {

    public static function __callStatic($method, $arguments) {
        if ('foo' === $method) {
            echo "static fooing\n";
        }
        return new static();
    }

    public function __call($method, $arguments) {
        if ('foo' === $method) {
            echo "instance fooing\n";
        }
    }

}

class Child extends Base {

}
```

Which would be used as:

```php
Child::foo()->foo();
```

The first `foo()` goes through `__callStatic()` in the `Base` class, because it's a static call. The second `foo()` goes through `__call()`, since it's a non-static call.

This would output:

```
static fooing
instance fooing
```

You can see it working [here](https://3v4l.org/NPgJN).